# E0312, C2664 Error When Trying to Pass a Vector Object as a Function Parameter

Tags: c++, function, vector

I am currently working on a project for school. The code that I'm creating is a bank account system. To access different members, I am having the user input their member ID which gets passed as one of the parameters to a function called `findMember`.
Here's the function:

```
int findMember(vector<Member> patron, int memID)
{
    int vectorSize;
    vectorSize = patron.size();
    for (int index = 0; index < vectorSize; index++)
    {
        if (memID == patron[index].getMemberID())
            return index;
    }
}
```

Here's the vector:

```
vector<Member*> patron; // Vector to store the members.
```

Here's the function call:

```
int acctID, memberIndex;
cout << "Enter your Account ID: ";
cin >> acctID;

memberIndex = findMember(patron, acctID);   // Helps find the index if the current stored member.
patron[memberIndex]->menu();                // Opens the current members 
storage location.
```

The error codes are these:

```
Error (active)  E0312   no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::vector<Member *, std::allocator<Member *>>" to "std::vector<Member, std::allocator<Member>>" exists
Error C2664 'int findMember(std::vector<Member,std::allocator<_Ty>>,int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<Member *,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'std::vector<Member,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
```

I have looked around the web for E0312 with no luck finding the reason why it gets thrown. C2664 had the same results. Where am I going wrong with my code?
Also, thanks in advance.

Comment: Good job submitting the question.  Now, look at the first parameter of findMember(), then compare that to your vector declaration.   Member vs Member* ? choose one and use it consistently.  Code looks good, otherwise.

Comment: Thank you! That helped get rid of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @2785528 for the response.

I was being inconsistent with the way I was passing the `vector<Member*>`. Once that error was fixed, all that was needed to be done was to change `patron[index].getMemberID()` to `patron[index]->getMemberID()`.